# Sorting a file based on a field that's not in a fixed position

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

i am a newbie in unix sort.
I have a set of data..example of lines:
as i tried sort -n command, it is given me this:
it start with 0_0 and the second one is 10_0, how i can make it to start at 0_0 then follow by 1_0 then 2_0 ....9_0...10_0..11_0...19_0...20_0....etc.?

Here is my input:

```
reg_0_0/clk 
reg_10_0/clk 
reg_11_0/clk 
reg_12_0/clk 
reg_13_0/clk 
reg_14_0/clk 
reg_15_0/clk 
reg_16_0/clk 
reg_17_0/clk 
reg_18_0/clk 
reg_19_0/clk 
reg_1_0/clk 
reg_20_0/clk 
reg_21_0/clk 
reg_22_0/clk 
reg_23_0/clk 
reg_24_0/clk 
reg_25_0/clk 
reg_26_0/clk 
reg_27_0/clk 
reg_28_0/clk 
reg_29_0/clk 
reg_2_0/clk 
reg_30_0/clk 
reg_31_0/clk 
reg_3_0/clk 
reg_4_0/clk 
reg_5_0/clk 
reg_6_0/clk 
reg_7_0/clk 
reg_8_0/clk 
reg_9_0/clk 
s_reg_0_0/clk 
s_reg_10_0/clk 
s_reg_11_0/clk 
s_reg_12_0/clk 
s_reg_13_0/clk 
s_reg_14_0/clk 
s_reg_15_0/clk 
s_reg_16_0/clk 
s_reg_17_0/clk 
s_reg_18_0/clk 
s_reg_19_0/clk 
s_reg_1_0/clk 
s_reg_20_0/clk 
s_reg_21_0/clk 
s_reg_22_0/clk 
s_reg_23_0/clk 
s_reg_24_0/clk 
s_reg_25_0/clk 
s_reg_26_0/clk 
s_reg_27_0/clk 
s_reg_28_0/clk 
s_reg_29_0/clk 
s_reg_2_0/clk 
s_reg_30_0/clk 
s_reg_31_0/clk 
s_reg_3_0/clk 
s_reg_4_0/clk 
s_reg_5_0/clk 
s_reg_6_0/clk 
s_reg_7_0/clk 
s_reg_8_0/clk 
s_reg_9_0/clk
```

Comment: in the future, post the minimal amount of data to illustrate your problem. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: read about `sort -t"_"` and the `+/-k[0-9]` options. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bad news is, you can't.  You don't have numbers, you have things that the human eye can discern as numbers, but sort isn't smart enough to parse the number out and sort on it.  You'll have to write some custom software to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` command on most modern systems is able to select fields and sort a particular field numerically.  For example:

```
sort -t _ -k 2 input.txt
```

This would work for the lines that look like `reg_1_0.txt`.  Of course, it would not work for the lines that contain an extra underscore before the sort field, like `s_reg_1_0.txt`, where you would need `-k 3`.

But there are tricks.

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1 &/' input.txt | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

This rewrites the input file so that the sort field is at the beginning of the line. It then sorts numerically, and then removes the first "field" of each line to restore the look of the original content. All using ubiquitous shell tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your file through `awk`, extract the number based on pattern (`reg_` vs `s_reg`), add that as an extra field and then sort it.  And finally use cut to remove the extra field.

```
awk -F_ '/^reg/ { print $0":"$2 } /^s_reg/ { print $0":"$3 }' file | sort -t: -k2,2n | cut -f1 -d:
```

Assuming that there are only two patterns, the above command can be further simplified as:

```
awk -F_ '/^reg/ { print $0":"$2; next } { print $0":"$3 }' file | sort -t: -k2,2n | cut -f1 -d:
```

Produces this output:

```
reg_0_0/clk
s_reg_0_0/clk
reg_1_0/clk
s_reg_1_0/clk
reg_2_0/clk
s_reg_2_0/clk
reg_3_0/clk
s_reg_3_0/clk
reg_4_0/clk
s_reg_4_0/clk
reg_5_0/clk
s_reg_5_0/clk
reg_6_0/clk
s_reg_6_0/clk
reg_7_0/clk
s_reg_7_0/clk
reg_8_0/clk
s_reg_8_0/clk
reg_9_0/clk
s_reg_9_0/clk
reg_10_0/clk
s_reg_10_0/clk
reg_11_0/clk
s_reg_11_0/clk
reg_12_0/clk
s_reg_12_0/clk
reg_13_0/clk
s_reg_13_0/clk
reg_14_0/clk
s_reg_14_0/clk
reg_15_0/clk
s_reg_15_0/clk
reg_16_0/clk
s_reg_16_0/clk
reg_17_0/clk
s_reg_17_0/clk
reg_18_0/clk
s_reg_18_0/clk
reg_19_0/clk
s_reg_19_0/clk
reg_20_0/clk
s_reg_20_0/clk
reg_21_0/clk
s_reg_21_0/clk
reg_22_0/clk
s_reg_22_0/clk
reg_23_0/clk
s_reg_23_0/clk
reg_24_0/clk
s_reg_24_0/clk
reg_25_0/clk
s_reg_25_0/clk
reg_26_0/clk
s_reg_26_0/clk
reg_27_0/clk
s_reg_27_0/clk
reg_28_0/clk
s_reg_28_0/clk
reg_29_0/clk
s_reg_29_0/clk
reg_30_0/clk
s_reg_30_0/clk
reg_31_0/clk
s_reg_31_0/clk
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
sed 's/g_/,/g' data.txt | sort -k2 -t, -n | sed 's/,/g_/g'
```

(assuming data.txt is a file of the lines to sort)

Since some of the elements to sort have two underscores instead of one, but sort only accepts a single character field separator, you could use sed to replace "g_" with "," and so that there's only one unique separator before the number for each (so the number is the second field always). Then after sorting, filter it through sed again and replace "," back with "g_".

Output:

```
reg_0_0/clk 
s_reg_0_0/clk 
reg_1_0/clk 
reg_2_0/clk 
reg_3_0/clk 
reg_4_0/clk 
reg_5_0/clk 
reg_6_0/clk 
reg_7_0/clk 
reg_8_0/clk 
reg_9_0/clk 
reg_10_0/clk 
s_reg_10_0/clk 
reg_11_0/clk 
s_reg_11_0/clk 
reg_12_0/clk 
s_reg_12_0/clk 
reg_13_0/clk 
s_reg_13_0/clk 
reg_14_0/clk 
s_reg_14_0/clk
reg_15_0/clk 
reg_16_0/clk 
reg_17_0/clk 
reg_18_0/clk 
reg_19_0/clk 
reg_20_0/clk 
reg_21_0/clk 
reg_22_0/clk 
reg_23_0/clk 
reg_24_0/clk 
reg_25_0/clk 
reg_26_0/clk 
reg_27_0/clk 
reg_28_0/clk 
reg_29_0/clk 
reg_30_0/clk 
reg_31_0/clk
```

If you only want unique elements, then just add a -u flag to sort.